# PNG driver chokes on raster gdal_transformed to ot byte

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, gdaldem

I'd like to extract a part of a DEM (data.linz.govt.nz wellinton lidar dem) and analyse it using gdaldem:

```
$ gdalinfo /vagrant/public/assets/GeoTIFFs/17a17d1fae/lenz-mean-annual-temperature.2193.tif               
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /vagrant/public/assets/GeoTIFFs/17a17d1fae/lenz-mean-annual-temperature.2193.tif
Size is 40827, 59684
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000",
    GEOGCS["NZGD2000",
        DATUM["New_Zealand_Geodetic_Datum_2000",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6167"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4167"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",173],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1600000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2193"]]
Origin = (1079625.000000000000000,6229400.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (25.000000000000000,-25.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1079625.000, 6229400.000) (167d22'19.08"E, 33d56'49.88"S)
Lower Left  ( 1079625.000, 4737300.000) (166d 6'50.17"E, 47d18'37.53"S)
Upper Right ( 2100300.000, 6229400.000) (178d24'42.42"E, 33d57'24.89"S)
Lower Right ( 2100300.000, 4737300.000) (179d37'20.18"E, 47d19'33.76"S)
Center      ( 1589962.500, 5483350.000) (172d52'51.63"E, 40d48' 2.84"S)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic
```

That my source.

```
$ gdal_translate -q -scale -ot Byte -a_nodata 0 -of GTiff -projwin 1744670.939733, 5432632.999810, 1759079.145998, 5417666.249587 -outsize 256 256 /vagrant/public/assets/GeoTIFFs/17a17d1fae/lenz-mean-annual-temperature.2193.tif /tmp/silverstripe-cache-php7.2.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1-vagrant/www-data/5ca433d05e16b
```

I tried all combinations, with or without scale, ot and a_nodata.

```
$ gdalinfo /tmp/silverstripe-cache-php7.2.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1-vagrant/www-data/5ca433d05e16b
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /tmp/silverstripe-cache-php7.2.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1-vagrant/www-data/5ca433d05e16b
Size is 256, 256
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000",
    GEOGCS["NZGD2000",
        DATUM["New_Zealand_Geodetic_Datum_2000",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6167"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4167"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",173],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1600000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2193"]]
Origin = (1744650.000000000000000,5432650.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (56.250000000000000,-58.496093750000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1744650.000, 5432650.000) (174d43'34.71"E, 41d14'40.64"S)
Lower Left  ( 1744650.000, 5417675.000) (174d43'47.53"E, 41d22'46.03"S)
Upper Right ( 1759050.000, 5432650.000) (174d53'53.08"E, 41d14'30.91"S)
Lower Right ( 1759050.000, 5417675.000) (174d54' 7.18"E, 41d22'36.25"S)
Center      ( 1751850.000, 5425162.500) (174d48'50.62"E, 41d18'38.57"S)
Band 1 Block=256x32 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic
```

gdaldem hillshade works but not slope or any of the other modes:

```
$ gdaldem slope /tmp/silverstripe-cache-php7.2.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1-vagrant/www-data/5ca433d05e16b /dev/stdout -q -of PNG
```

returns the error:

```
ERROR 6: PNG driver doesn't support data type Float32. Only eight bit (Byte) and sixteen bit (UInt16) bands supported.
```

How do I translate the original raster so that conforms with what gdaldem slope and co expect?

Comment: Think what the error message says and don't try to create png but create a GeoTIFF instead with `-ot GTiff`. In the first clipping command leave out `-ot Byte`. You should not convert DEM into 8 bit.

Comment: Your gdaldem slope needs to be output to a format that *does* support floating point data, like GeoTIFF (-of GTIFF) or ERDAS Imagine (-of HFA) or the lowest form ASCII Grid (-of AAIGRID).. you have told it to output to a PNG which only supports 8 bit unsigned so gdaldem is refusing to write to this driver. Why are you trying to scale your DEM to 8 bit? It should be at least 16 bit integer, most likely 32 bit float or 64 bit float (double), scaling to 8 bit is not fit for any further processing but for display only.

Comment: The idea is to generate a 256*256 PNG map tile to use with leaflet.

Comment: Is my problem that the input from the translation contains data that is neither byte nor UInt16 or that gdaldem cannot do slopes in PNG? Again hillshade works, just not the others.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer in the fine print: slope will output a 32-bit float and so will aspect, so no PNG without post processing.

No idea what type TRI and TPI spit out.

Color-relief however returns RGB or RGBA. I had initially missed the color map file, so this is working now.

```
gdaldem color-relief /tmp/silverstripe-cache-php7.2.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1-vagrant/www-data/5ca433d05e16b color_relief.txt /dev/stdout -q -of PNG -alpha
```